# How to display text on the same line using @media?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some text which I have been able to separate out and display on the same line using an `@media` query.

The CSS itself works without an `@media` query, in mobile, but in desktop it doesn't, so I applied an `@media` query below `768px` which worked in mobile. As soon as I tried to apply the CSS to desktop though, through an @media query above `768px`, namely `768px` to `5000px`, it doesn't display how I want it.

Basically I want the text on the same line in mobile, with a slight space in between, which I have achieved, and the same in desktop.

My desktop `@media` query isn't working though.

Here is my CSS code:

```
@media (max-width: 5000px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .findanevent {
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 5000px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .event {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="lasvegas">
Events</div>
<div class="findanevent"> </div>
<div class="event_wrapper"><a 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an- 
event/"><span id="findanevent" 
class="event">Find an Event</span>. 
</a>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post- 
an-event/"><span id="postanevent" 
class="event">Post an Event</span>. 
</a></div>
```

Here is the page, if it helps: https://adsler.co.uk/events/

Comment: Have you set `width=device width` in the `header`? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Where's the other half of your HTML anchor tag?

Comment: `<div class="lasvegas">Events</div>
<div class="findanevent"></div>
<div class="event_wrapper"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an- 
event">
<span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span></a>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event</a></div>`

Comment: @AndyHoffman Thanks but do you really think it's a viewport issue, even one which can't be rectified by an, media query or some other css?

Comment: Please see updated question... Html..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust margins to your need.

```css
.event_wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'a b c'
                       'd e f';
}


.Lable1{
  grid-area: b;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -70px;
}

.Lable2{
  grid-area: d;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left:20%;
}

.Lable3{
  grid-area:f;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right:20%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="event_wrapper">
      <div class="Lable1"><h2>Events</h2><br></div>
  <div class="Lable2"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/">
    <span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span>.</a></div>
  <div class="Lable3"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/">
    <span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span>.</a></div>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you want Post an Event and Find an Event on the same line under Events?

Comment: Thanks. It says unexpected grid token `1fr` and won't publish

Comment: Ok. Separated `1` from `fr` and it works. Brill. Thanks dude. The only thing is that in desktop they are very far apart? Do I rectify using margin?

Comment: Or would i set the whole thing in an @media query above 769px?

Comment: And perhaps line-height slightly lower in desktop. Rectify using media query? Also, how come my font is different in desktop? Shouldn't it stay the same as mobile?

Comment: @Stack If they are far apart, just add margins-left or margin right to either label for your styling. For mobile, add `@media query` and copy paste the code within { } then edit the styling to your needs.

Comment: OK thanks so much for your time. Great job @MTBthePRO